# SQL оптимизация запроса, получить два последних значения по штампу времени

Tags: sql, postgresql

Есть большая таблица данными, следующего формата:

| id | name(string) | value(double) | dt(timestamp) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |

Необходимо написать запрос, который возвращает два последних значения по штампу времени и имени параметра. Сейчас запрос выглядит следующим образом:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tablename
WHERE name="someparam_1"
ORDER BY dt DESC LIMIT 2;
```

Каким образом можно оптимизировать данный запрос?

Comment: создать индекс из полей name, dt если его еще нет

Comment: Создать партиции если индекс есть и этого мало :)